# What does 'a, b, c = input().split()' mean in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a, b, c = input().split()
```

I have encountered a problem while learning python programming, i think this is a basic problem but i don't understand how that statement works.
Can anyone help me with the answer?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Do you know what `input().split()` is expected to produce?  If so (it's presumably supposed to be a list of three words entered by the user), then try writing the line with that literal value in its place: `a, b, c = ["spam", "eggs", "spam"]`.  Does that help make it easier to see what the assignment is doing?

Comment: A nice trick is to temporary use a print instead: `print(input().split())` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known commonly as iterable unpacking. If an item is iterable, you can use it to initialize multiple variables at once. A common pattern you've probably already seen is tuple unpacking, such as:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

This is somewhat equivalent to writing:

```
vals = (1, 2)
a = vals[1]
b = vals[2]
```

It is possible to perform this on more than just tuples. Here's some examples which all produce similar results:

```
a, b = 1, 2
a, b = [1, 2]

# Note: when a set is used as an iterable, 
# the ordering of assignment is undefined.
a, b = {1, 2}

# Note: when a dictionary is used as an iterable, 
# only the keys are evaluated
a, b = {1: 'a', 2: 'b'}

# You can also use a generator:
def foo():
    yield 1
    yield 2

a, b = foo()
```

For the above examples to work, the size of the iterable must match the number of arguments provided. For example:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = 1, 2, 3
    ^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

In cases where there are an unknown amount of variables and you only want to grab a certain set of them, you can use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/). In this method you can define a variable in the expansion as a catch-all. From the linked PEP, you have the example:

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> a
0
>>> c
4
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

Iterable unpacking can also be used in for loops, which is very commonly used when iterating through a dictionary. `dict.items()` returns an iterable of pair iterables, allowing you to write code such as this:

```
>>> data = {1:2, 3:4}
>>> for key, value in data.items():
...     print(key, value)
1 2
3 4
```

Unpacking can also be used in more nested contexts, allowing you to unpack some pretty complex structures, so use it mindfully!

```
>>> data = [
...     [1, [2, [3, 4, 5, 6]]],
...     [1, [2, [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]],
... ]
>>> for a, [b, [c, *_, d]] in data:
...     print(a, b, c, d)
1 2 3 6
1 2 3 7
```